# How to call javascript function as well as server side function on DropDownList Item changed

Tags: javascript, .net

I have a dropdown. What I want is, when user changes the dropdown list item then to show image of loading and then to go server side and execute my OnselectedIndexChenged event.

But I am able to call only one at a time. If javascript call is successful then it is not calling server side.

I called javascript through onchange event.

I tried with this

Comment: Could you call the server-side function via AJAX from your JS function?

Comment: ya that I didn't tried, but can be done, I think. But why both the events are not working at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, you can register the javascript on SelectedIndexChanged of combo.

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("ClientScript", script);
```

You can do whatevery ou want in your javascript and then call button.Click() at the end of your javascript. This button should run on server-side and shouldn't have any JS attached to it.

You can do whatever you want on that buttons click(code-behind). Remember to make that button invisible ;)